# Can't properly change my LinearLayout to ListView

Tags: android, mysql, listview

Here is ,my code for selecting images and texts from mysql database through php.And it is displaying in a linearlayout in a scrollview.All i want to do is change my layout to listview like [this example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiLhw.jpg)
I tried listview and other many ways but its not working properly.I'm new in android,so im trying for a long time.Please help me by editing my code for my requirement.Please.

**JAVA**

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    public class News_and_events extends Fragment {

        private String jsonResult;
        private String url = "http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/select.php";
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        ImageView img;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;


       // alert dialog manager
        AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

        // Internet detector
        ConnectionDetector cd;

         InputStream is=null;
         String result=null;
            String line=null;
            int code;

        public News_and_events(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_and_events, container, false);

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(rootView.getContext());

            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(getActivity(),
                        "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                //return.rootView;
                return rootView;
            }

            accessWebService();
            return rootView;
        }

        // Async Task to access the web
         private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          @Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);


           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
           try {

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
              response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            }

           catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
          }

           private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
           String rLine = "";
           StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
           BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

           try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             answer.append(rLine);
            }
           }
            catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
              "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           return answer;
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           display();
          }
         }// end async task

         public void accessWebService() {
          JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
          // passes values for the urls string array
          task.execute(new String[] { url });
         }

         // build hash set for list view
         public void display() {


          try {
           JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
           JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("news_details");
           LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newslayout); 
           //LinearLayout headLN=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headsection);

           for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
               JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                final String head = jsonChildNode.optString("title");
                final String details = jsonChildNode.optString("text");
                final String date = jsonChildNode.optString("date");
                final String image = jsonChildNode.optString("img");
                //final String time = jsonChildNode.optString("time");
                //img = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
                //new LoadImage().execute("http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/images/"+image);

                img = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                LoadImage ldimg=new LoadImage();
                ldimg.setImage(img);
                ldimg.execute("http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/images/"+image);


                TextView headln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
                headln.setText(head); // News Headlines
                headln.setTextSize(16);
                headln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                headln.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                headln.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcd14"));
              //  headln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubg);
                headln.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
              //  headln.setHeight(50);
                headln.setClickable(true);


                TextView dateln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
                dateln.setText(date); // News Headlines
                dateln.setTextSize(12);
                dateln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                dateln.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                //dateln.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f20056"));
                dateln.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                dateln.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 10);
                dateln.setWidth(100);
                dateln.setClickable(true);



                View sep=new View(this.getActivity());
                sep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#252525"));
                sep.setMinimumHeight(10);

                TextView detailsln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
                detailsln.setText(details); // News Details
                detailsln.setTextSize(12);
                detailsln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                detailsln.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                detailsln.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                int width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                int height = 200;
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
               img.setLayoutParams(parms);
               parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
               img.setPaddingRelative (15, 15, 15, 15);

                MainLL.addView(headln);
                MainLL.addView(dateln);
             //   MainLL.addView(photo);
                MainLL.addView(img);
                MainLL.addView(detailsln);
                MainLL.addView(sep);

                img.setClickable(true);

               // img.buildDrawingCache();  
               // final Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();
                headln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                        intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("image", image);
                        startActivity(intent);       

                    }
                });

                dateln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                    intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("image", image);
                    startActivity(intent);       
                    }
                });

                img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                    intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("image", image);
                    startActivity(intent);       
                    }
                });

                detailsln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                        intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                        intent.putExtra("image", image);
                        startActivity(intent);       
                        }
                    });
           }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
           }

         private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
             ImageView img;
                         @Override
                             protected void onPreExecute() {
                                 super.onPreExecute();

                                 pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
                                 pDialog.show();


                         }
             public void setImage(ImageView img ){
             this.img=img;
             }

             protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
                 try {
                     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).openStream());
                     } 
                 catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                 return bitmap;
             }

             protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
                  if(image != null){
                      img.setImageBitmap(image);

                      pDialog.dismiss(); 
                  }
                  pDialog.dismiss(); 
             } 

         }

         public static boolean isInternetReachable()
         {
             try {
                 //make a URL to a known source
                 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

                 //open a connection to that source
                 HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                 //trying to retrieve data from the source. If there
                 //is no connection, this line will fail
                 Object objData = urlConnect.getContent();

             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 return false;
             }
             catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 return false;
             }
             return true;
         }
    }
```

**XML**

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

<sub>(source: [codelearn.org](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/assets/list_view/list-view-example-1-3928c884e90efde573574bee3a89e868.jpg))</sub>

```
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"

         >

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/newslayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"

                >     

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: All you need is creating a layout for single row only. Then, you should populate that layout in listview with different values ( retrieved from you web service may be). You can find tons of resources for this on web.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call display() from within AsyncTask to display results in listview.

You should follow the following steps

1. Inside on create, Call AsyncTask to fetch the data from server and populate this into an Array List. While async task is running, make sure you display a progress dialogue so that user cannot do anything in the UI thread.
2. Inside on create, do initialize your listview.
3. inside on Post execute of AsyncTask, after you have populated all the elements in the arraylist, call the adapter to populate the listview.
4. Define an adapter which extends BaseAdapter using which you can populate the listview from the array list.

You may want to check out [this link](http://semycolon.blogspot.in/2014/11/first-android-app-step-7-populate.html) for a similar working example.